# What do the covariance and correlation tell me about two values?

Tags: correlation, interaction, standard-deviation, covariance, ratio

I started reading a bit about probabilities and how they are used in investing. When reading about covariance and correlation, I got a bit confused about what they tell me about the two values I compare.

Let's say I have cov(x,y). Am I correct to say that if x were to move up by 1, y would move up by cov(x,y) on average?

Also if I have correlation(x,y), would this means that if x were to move up by one standard deviation s_x, y were to move up by correlation(x,y)*s_y on average?

Apologies in advance if my formatting/use of symbols is incorrect.